# Insert nested arrays if nested array does not exist

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert new data if the does not exist in the nested array, so far I'm able to add if they don't exist, but it's removing the previous data, any help would be appreciated.

Arrays

```
const posts = 
  [ { _id: 1
    , message: 'this is post one'
    , likes:    [ { id: 111221, user: 'random 1' } , { id: 2223422, user:'random 2' } ] 
    , comments: [ { id: 332233, message: 'random comment' } , { id: 2344444, message:'another random comment' } ] 
  }] 
const comments = 
  [ { id: 3333, message: 'this is comment 1' } 
  , { id: 4444, message: 'this is comment 2' } 
  ] 
const likes = 
  [ { id: 1111, user: 'Peter' } 
  , { id: 2222, user: 'John'  } 
  ]
```

expected output

```
const newPost = 
  [ { _id: 1
    , message: 'this is post one'
    , likes:    [ 
        { id: 1111, user: 'Peter' } ,
        { id: 111221, user: 'random 1' } , 
        { id: 2223422, user:'random 2' } ,
        { id: 2222, user: 'John'  }
    ] 
    , comments: [ 
        { id: 3333, message: 'this is comment 1' } ,
        { id: 4444, message: 'this is comment 2' },
        { id: 332233, message: 'random comment' } , 
        { id: 2344444, message:'another random comment' } 
    ] 
  }]
```

what I've tried

```
const newPosts = posts.map(post => ({
    ...post,
    likes: likes.filter(like => !post.likes.map(like => like.id).includes(like.id)),
    comments: comments.filter(comment => !post.comments.map(comment => comment.id).includes(comment.id)),
}))

console.log(newPosts)
```

Comment: I'm not following. If you got a variable called `posts`, then why do you only have one item in it? Because if `posts` should contain more items than `_id: 1`, then how can you know which item in `likes` and `comments` that should go into which item?

Comment: check then answer I've just provided, this was specifically made to grab changes from a change stream from mongo db which contains 3 arrays of the new (post,comment & likes) which comes from three different sockets (posts,comment &likes) which contain the FK of their parent id (post), so then they are merged with a separate function by ID, containing the new array post, once that is done I compare the old state of posts breaking it down and inserting the new values of the array that has merged from the three sockets, then state is updated with the included updates, if that makes sense

Comment: more conditioning would be needed later by this is atleast a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm too tired, but I would just merge the arrays together. Your post didn't mention that you needed to check whether the comments in the variable `comments` already could exist in posts[0].comments (`_id: 1`).

```js
const posts = [{
  _id: 1,
  message: 'this is post one',
  likes: [{
    id: 111221,
    user: 'random 1'
  }, {
    id: 2223422,
    user: 'random 2'
  }],
  comments: [{
    id: 332233,
    message: 'random comment'
  }, {
    id: 2344444,
    message: 'another random comment'
  }]
}]

const comments = [{
  id: 3333,
  message: 'this is comment 1'
}, {
  id: 4444,
  message: 'this is comment 2'
}]
const likes = [{
  id: 1111,
  user: 'Peter'
}, {
  id: 2222,
  user: 'John'
}]

const addTo = (posts, comments, likes) => {
  let newPostInstance = [...posts][0];
  
  newPostInstance.comments = [...newPostInstance.comments, ...comments];
  newPostInstance.likes    = [...newPostInstance.likes, ...likes];
  
  return newPostInstance;
}

const newPost = addTo(posts, comments, likes);

console.log(newPost)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const posts1 = 
  [ { _id: 1
    , message: 'this is post one'
    , likes:    [ { id: 111222221, user: 'random 1' } , { id: 2223422, user:'random 2' } ] 
    , comments: [ { id: 3322222233, message: 'random comment' } , { id: 2344444, message:'another random comment' } ] 
  }] 


  const posts = 
  [ { _id: 1
    , message: 'this is post one'
    , likes:    [ { id: 111221, user: 'random 1asdasdasd' } , { id: 2223422, user:'random 2asdasdasd' } ] 
    , comments: [ { id: 332233, message: 'rasdasdasd' } , { id: 2344444, message:'asdasdasdwwwwww' } ] 
  }] 

if(posts.filter(r => r.comments) !== posts1.filter(r => r.comments)){
    const a = posts.map(({likes,_id,message, ...o}) => ({...o.comments}))
    const b = posts1.map(({likes,_id,message, ...o}) => ({...o.comments}))
    const c = posts.map(({comments,_id,message, ...o}) => ({...o.likes}))
    const d = posts1.map(({comments,_id,message, ...o}) => ({...o.likes}))

    const newComments = [...a,...b]
    const newLikes = [...c,...d]

    const returnFlattenObject = (arr) => {
        const flatObject = {};
        for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
           for(const property in arr[i]){
              flatObject[`${property}_${i}`] = arr[i][property];
           }
        };
        return flatObject;
    }

    posts.map(({comments,likes, ...o}) => ({
        ...o,
        comments: returnFlattenObject(newComments),
        likes: returnFlattenObject(newLikes)
    }))
} else {
    console.log('exists')
}
```

result

```
[{…}]
0:
comments:
0_0: {id: 332233, message: 'rasdasdasd'}
0_1: {id: 3322222233, message: 'random comment'}
1_0: {id: 2344444, message: 'asdasdasdwwwwww'}
1_1: {id: 2344444, message: 'another random comment'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
likes:
0_0: {id: 111221, user: 'random 1'}
0_1: {id: 111222221, user: 'random 1'}
1_0: {id: 2223422, user: 'random 2'}
1_1: {id: 2223422, user: 'random 2'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
message: "this is post one"
_id: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```